# Read and Write Files in C

Tags: c, file

My assignment:

> Write a program that asks the user whether to read or write a file.  If writing a file, it then asks for a line of text, and writes it to a file.  If reading, it reads the files and outputs it to the screen.  The text is written out in non-binary mode - which is different than the file reading and writing for project #2.  Remember how we used `fgets()` with string input. There is also an `fputs()`.

I am trying to code the write section, but I cannot figure out what my mistake is. Also I do not really know how to create the read section. Do I only have to open the file then?

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HOLD_SCREEN while(getchar()!='q')

int write() {
    int num;
    FILE*fptr;
    fptr = fopen_s;
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter num: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &num);
    fprintf(fptr, "%d", num);
    fclose(fptr);
    return(0);
}

int main(void) {
    while (1) {
        printf("\n\tEnter an option: (R)ead or (W)rite a file or enter a q if you want to quit: ");
        char buf[50];
        buf[0] = '\0';
        scanf_s("%s", buf, 50);
        switch (toupper(buf[0])) {
        case 'W':
            write();
            break;
        case 'R':
            printInventory();
            break;
        case 'Q':
            return(0);
        }
    }

    HOLD_SCREEN;
    return(0);
}
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: `fptr = fopen_s;` ?? Where is the filename and the aditional safety checks?

Comment: And what errors and warnings does your compiler give you when you try compiling your code?

Comment: try `fptr = fopen("myfile.txt","w");`

Comment: And don't use `scanf_s()`.  It's no safer than normal `scanf()` and it's not portable.  Point anyone pushing Annex K elements of C such as `scanf_s()` towards this: [Field Experience With Annex K — Bounds Checking Interfaces](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1967.htm):  "As a result of the numerous deviations from the specification the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable. "

Comment: When reading the R/W/q option at the start I suggest you use `getchar` instead of `scanf_s`.

Answer (score 0):

For writing:

`fopen_s` requires 3 parameters,

```
errno_t fopen_s(FILE** pFile, const char *filename, const char *mode);
```

an example being (in write mode)

```
errno_t err;
FILE *fptr
err = fopen_s(&fptr, "text.txt", "w" );
```

I am also taking some liberties and guessing this is the microsoft stack by the use of `fopen_s` instead of `fopen`. Otherwise, you should be using `fopen` like

```
FILE *fptr
fptr= fopen("text.txt", "w");
```

For reading:

Similar except the 3rd parameter would be `err = fopen_s(&fptr, "text.txt", "r" );` or `fptr = fopen("text.txt, "r")` and use `fgets` to read a line of input (lots of examples out there).